# How to edit message in the Lync that was already sent?

Tags: lync-2013

Is there a way to edit a message text for a message that was sent in the conversation? In Skype, for instance, one can right-click the message body and choose to edit the message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am using Lync in the office everyday and I have looked for this functionality previously (no luck).

A quick search shows no information on the subject. Lync's FAQ also does not mention such feature - and its likely that this can not be done. If this functionality would exist, Microsoft would brag about it all over the place.

One thing that is relevant to the subject can be found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/lync-help/faq-about-lync-im-HA102970351.aspx#_Toc377123292). FAQ clearly states that messages cannot be recalled after sending. Recalling messages and editing messages after sending are very similar functions and I believe if you cannot recall - you cannot edit.

Comment: I'd say recalling and editing are very different functions.

Comment: They are effectively the same. Editing = Recalling + Re-sending a new one  with new content. If you cannot recall you cannot edit

Comment: Depends how it's implemented.  The sending app will be aware of the last line sent, so it wouldn't necessarily require a recall.

Answer (score 0):

My vision is that editing messages in Lync is disabled/not implemented, because lync is a "Skype for business" and most companies have "records management policies" that restrict and forbids tampering with any communication. Once message has been transmitted, it's illegal to change it's content. Probably that is the case.